# create an classification for months ordered

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I'm trying to create an column in my query to show an ordered classification ( show 1, 2, 3 ( as in first, second, third ...)) relative to date... in my current query i have filtered data from the last 12 months ( as example, from 1-9-2016 to 31-8-2017)

using `DATEADD(mm; DATEDIFF(m; - 1; GETDATE()) - 12; 0)`

for the first date and

`DATEADD(s; - 1; DATEADD(mm; DATEDIFF(m; 0; GETDATE()) + 1; 0))`

for the last day of the current month. And i also have two columns, one with the month and other with the year, both extracted from a document date column present in the data ( i'm using

`MONTH(dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.dtmData)` and `YEAR(dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.dtmData))`.

My goal is to have a column showing something like this :

If the month is the first from the interval ( if is month 9 and year 2016 ) is has to show 1 , if is the second ( month 10 and year 2016) , show 2, all continuously until the current month ( that is 8 and year 2017) and showing 12.

If the values where static i could do a simple case and would achieve what i wanted. My problem is that since when i get the data filtered by my current date and the 12 months behind, i don't manage to get the same result because i don't know exactly what i should do in the CASE expression.

so that it could help my columns are :

```
Item ; Qty ; Month ; Year ; dtmData ; orderedMonth
```

ORIGINAL QUERY :

```
SELECT DISTINCT DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, - 1, GETDATE()) - 12, 0)                            AS DATA_INI,
  DATEADD(s,                            - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)) AS DATA_FIM,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.Id,
  MONTH(dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.dtmData)                                      AS Mes,
  YEAR(dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.dtmData)                                       AS Ano,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.fltValorMercadoriaSIVA * dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.intSinal AS Mercadoria,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.fltValorLiquido        * dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.intSinal AS ValorLiquido,
  CASE
    WHEN tbl_tipos_documentos.bitconsideraqtdmapas = 1
    THEN (Mov_Venda_Lin.fltQuantidade * mov_venda_cab.intsinal)
    ELSE 0
  END                                      AS Quantidade,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodSeccao           AS Seccao,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.strAbrevTpDoc          AS TpDoc,
  dbo.Tbl_Tipos_Documentos.strDescricao    AS DescTpDoc,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.intNumLinha            AS Linha,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodExercicio        AS Exercicio,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.strAbrevMoeda          AS Moeda,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.fltCambio              AS Cambio,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodArtigo           AS Artigo,
  dbo.Tbl_Gce_Artigos.strDescricao         AS DescArtigo,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodClassMovStk      AS MovStk,
  dbo.Tbl_ClassificacaoMovStk.strDescricao AS DescMovStk,
  CASE
    WHEN mov_venda_cab.inttpentidade = 0
    THEN tbl_gce_tipos_entidade.strcodigo
    ELSE NULL
  END AS TpEntidade,
  CASE
    WHEN mov_venda_cab.inttpentidade = 0
    THEN tbl_gce_tipos_entidade.strdescricao
    ELSE NULL
  END AS DescTpEntidade,
  CASE
    WHEN mov_venda_cab.intcodentidade <> 0
    THEN mov_venda_cab.intcodentidade
    ELSE NULL
  END AS CodEntidade,
  CASE
    WHEN mov_venda_cab.inttpentidade  = 0
    AND mov_venda_cab.intcodentidade <> 0
    THEN 'Cliente'
    WHEN mov_venda_cab.inttpentidade  = 1
    AND mov_venda_cab.intcodentidade <> 0
    THEN 'Outro Devedor'
    ELSE NULL
  END AS TipoEntidade,
  CASE
    WHEN mov_venda_cab.inttpentidade = 0
    THEN tbl_clientes.strnome
    ELSE tbl_outros_devedores.strnome
  END                                    AS DescNome,
  dbo.Tbl_SubZonas.strAbrevZona          AS Zona,
  dbo.Tbl_Zonas.strDescricao             AS DescZona,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.strAbrevSubZona      AS SubZona,
  dbo.Tbl_SubZonas.strDescricao          AS DescSubZona,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.intCodVendedor       AS Vendedor,
  dbo.Tbl_Gce_Vendedores.strNome         AS DescNomeVend,
  dbo.Tbl_Gce_Artigos.strCodCategoria    AS Categoria,
  dbo.Tbl_Gce_Categorias.strDescricao    AS DescCategoria,
  dbo.Tbl_Gce_Artigos.strTpArtigo        AS TpArtigo,
  dbo.Tbl_Gce_Tipos_Artigos.strDescricao AS DescTpArtigo,
  CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(13))              AS CodFamiliaAgrup,
  CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(35))              AS DescFamAgrup,
  CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(13))              AS CodFamiliaRes,
  CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(35))              AS DescFamRes,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.strForteAbrevMoeda   AS abrevmoeda,
  dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.fltForteCambio       AS fortecambio
FROM dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin WITH (NOLOCK)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodSeccao     = dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.strCodSeccao
  AND dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.strAbrevTpDoc   = dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.strAbrevTpDoc
  AND dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodExercicio = dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.strCodExercicio
  AND dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.intNumero       = dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.intNumero
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Gce_Armazens WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodArmazem = dbo.Tbl_Gce_Armazens.strCodigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Gce_Artigos WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Tbl_Gce_Artigos.strCodigo = dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodArtigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Gce_ArtigosFamilias WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Tbl_Gce_Artigos.strCodigo = dbo.Tbl_Gce_ArtigosFamilias.strCodArtigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Gce_Familias WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Tbl_Gce_ArtigosFamilias.strCodFamilia = dbo.Tbl_Gce_Familias.strCodigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Gce_ArtigosReferencias WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Tbl_Gce_Artigos.strCodigo = dbo.Tbl_Gce_ArtigosReferencias.strCodArtigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Gce_Referencias WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Tbl_Gce_ArtigosReferencias.strCodReferencia = dbo.Tbl_Gce_Referencias.strCodigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Gce_Tipos_Artigos WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Tbl_Gce_Artigos.strTpArtigo = dbo.Tbl_Gce_Tipos_Artigos.strCodigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Clientes WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.intCodEntidade = dbo.Tbl_Clientes.intCodigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Direccoes WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.intCodEntidade = dbo.Tbl_Direccoes.intCodigo
  AND dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.intDireccao   = dbo.Tbl_Direccoes.intNumero
  AND dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.intTpEntidade = dbo.Tbl_Direccoes.intTp_Entidade
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Outros_Devedores WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.intCodEntidade = dbo.Tbl_Outros_Devedores.intCodigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Gce_Vendedores WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.intCodVendedor = dbo.Tbl_Gce_Vendedores.intCodigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Tipos_Documentos WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.strAbrevTpDoc = dbo.Tbl_Tipos_Documentos.strAbreviatura
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_SubZonas WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.strAbrevSubZona = dbo.Tbl_SubZonas.strAbreviatura
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Zonas WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Tbl_SubZonas.strAbrevZona = dbo.Tbl_Zonas.strAbreviatura
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Gce_Categorias WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Tbl_Gce_Artigos.strCodCategoria = dbo.Tbl_Gce_Categorias.strCodigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Gce_Seccoes WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.strCodSeccao = dbo.Tbl_Gce_Seccoes.strCodigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_Gce_Tipos_Entidade WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Tbl_Clientes.strTpEntidade = dbo.Tbl_Gce_Tipos_Entidade.strCodigo
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Tbl_ClassificacaoMovStk WITH (NOLOCK)
  ON dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.strCodClassMovStk = dbo.Tbl_ClassificacaoMovStk.strCodigo
WHERE (dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.intTpEntidade = 0
  OR dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.intTpEntidade    IS NULL)
  AND (dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.strAbrevTpDoc                            IN ('CRFCX', 'FACIV', 'FACTC', 'FCTA', 'LANIV', 'LOFX', 'LONC', 'LXANI', 'NCFCX', 'NFACC', 'NFACE', 'NFACM', 'NFACT', 'NNCRC', 'NNCRE', 'NNCRM', 'NNDEB', 'NNDEC', 'NNDEV', 'NVDIC', 'NVDIN', 'XLACC', 'XLACD'))
  AND (dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.strCodSeccao                             IN ('1', 'ENCT1', 'ENCT2', 'ENCT3', 'ENCT4', 'ENCT5', 'ENCT6'))
  AND (dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.dtmData         > DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, - 1, GETDATE()) - 12, 0))
  AND (dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.dtmData        <= DATEADD(s,              - 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m, 0, GETDATE()) + 1, 0)))
  AND (dbo.Mov_Venda_Lin.intTpLinha      > 2)
  AND (dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.bitAnulado      = 0)
  AND (dbo.Mov_Venda_Cab.bitConvertido   = 0)
```

Comment: what db server are you using? Please list your current query

Comment: Sql Server 2012... Original query is to long to post here ...

Comment: Added original query ( sorry, it's a bit long ... that's why i've simplified it ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily there's a much less complicated method than using a bunch of `CASE` statements.  You can use the `ROW_NUMBER` function.

First, don't split your dates into month and year.  Just use `Getdate()` to calculate your desired range and compare your source dates to that.  Then you add the `ROW_NUMBER` to get your ordering output:

```
SELECT 
    *
    ,ordered_output = (ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY grouping_field ORDER BY cast(dtmData as datetime) ASC))
FROM Mov_Venda_Cab
WHERE cast(dtmData as datetime) >= getdate() - 365
```

This example assumes your have some ID field or similar on which your want to group your output, represented by `grouping_field` in the example.  Your results would look like:

```
grouping_field  dtmData    ordered_output 
1               8/1/2017     1
1               8/2/2017     2
1               8/3/2017     3
2               8/1/2017     1
2               8/2/2017     2
2               8/3/2017     3
```

If you don't want to group your output, just ordering everything by the date, you can omit the `PARTITION BY grouping_field` text.  You'd get instead something like:

```
dtmData    ordered_output 
8/1/2017     1
8/2/2017     2
8/3/2017     3
8/4/2017     4
8/5/2017     5
8/6/2017     6
```

**EDIT**: Asker clarified that all records with the same month should get the same ordered output.

To do that you first need to assign each month/year combo a rank and rejoin that to the main table using two layers of subqueries:

```
SELECT b.*, c.month_rank
from Mov_Venda_Cab as b
inner join
    (select mnt, yr, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY A.yr, A.mnt) AS month_rank
    from (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            MONTH(dtmData) as mnt
            , YEAR(dtmData) as yr
        from Mov_Venda_Cab
        WHERE cast(dtmData as datetime) >= getdate() - 365
        ) as a
    ) as c
on MONTH(b.dtmData) = c.mnt and YEAR(b.dtmData) = c.yr
```

Comment: almost worked ... ordered output should be done by month, so if i use with partition ( ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY mov_venda_cab.dtmdata ORDER BY mov_venda_cab.dtmdata ASC) as classific) i get all lines as number 1 ... if i discard PARTITION i get all lines numbered asn 1,2,3,4,.....128999, and so on ... because is grouping by line and not by month/year.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm totally understanding your problem here, but if you want to group by month you can pull the month out of `dtmData` and partition by that

Comment: I did that ... and almost got what i wanted. Got all lines from 

What i want is this :

Comment: Sounds like you'll just need to fiddle with it to account for the details of your data that aren't obvious from your question :-)

Comment: I did that ... and almost got what i wanted.  

What i want is this :
[code]
Item |   Qty | dtmData | Month | Year | ORDERED_OUTPUT
01.001 | 12 | 10/09/2016 | 9 | 2016 | 1
01.002 | 5 | 22/09/2016 | 9 | 2016 | 1
01.001| 3| 16/10/2016| 10 | 2016 | 2
01.001| 7 | 01/11/2016| 11 | 2016 | 3
01.002| 10 | 14/11/2016| 11 | 2016 | 3
02.004| 2 | 22/11/2016 | 11 | 2016 | 3
01.001| 10 | 18/12/2016 | 12 | 2016 | 4
01.002| 8 | 10/01/2017 | 1 | 2017 | 5[code]

Basically, no matter how many lines i have in a month, all the lines should get the same "rank" . Hope i could clarify a bit better...

Comment: @NunoMarques ok, added another option to reflect all months getting the same rank

Comment: I think you want dense_rank vs row_number  since multiple records could have 1.

Comment: Thank you so much, Rominus ... it did work ... i had to tweak a bit because of the amount of columns needed, but did your query and it worked flawlessly. Thank you so much